# Ext.Button passing along the record id to the handler

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using `ExtJS 3`, I have a button which has a `handler` and I want to pass along the `record` id to the `handler` function but I am not sure how.

**The code I have for the button is as follows:**

```
new Ext.Button({
    text: 'Delete Stuff Here',
    handler: function() {
        DeleteStuff();
    }
})
```

and **the function as follows:**

```
function DeleteStuff() {
    alert(record.id);
}
```

I can't seem to get it going, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is your `record`?

Answer (score 0):

I never used ExtJS3 but I use ExtJS 6 so maybe my answer was not correct.

When I want to use handler params, I set them like that:

```
new Ext.Button({
    text: 'Delete Stuff Here',
    handler: 'DeleteStuff'
})
```

after that, your DeleteStuff function have one params is ***btn*** is your btn cmp.

Now, we have to know where is your record. It is on your ctrller, it's a button on grid (so you can do btn.$widgetrecord or something like that on ExtJS3) or is a view params ?